# How to save image to google drive using php

Tags: php

i want to save image on google drive on button click using core php. I don't know anything about it. Got some examples of API but i don't know about API and all. So please give me link or solution that describes from initial. Thank You

Comment: show some code...as to what have you tried...before this questions gets marked down

Comment: Please read it from google. This is not the portal to teach you. We here solve only specific problems. If you have any problem in implementing anything, please update here.

Comment: I did not do anything yet, i am saving my images to my computer's folder and now i want to save images on google drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use [DROPzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) & then connecto to google

```
imagesDropzoneInstance = new Dropzone '#imagesDropzone',
  url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=media'
  method: 'post'
  maxFileSize: 5
  paramName: 'images-dropzone-input'
  headers:
    'Authorization': "Bearer #{ uploadBundle.accessToken }"
  addRemoveLinks: 'dictRemoveFile'

imagesDropzoneInstance.uploadFiles = (files) ->
  uploadFiles: (files) ->

    .. copy the uploadFiles method of Dropzone, modify, then paste here..

    # Add the end:
    xhr.send files[0] # This overrides the default upload behavior.
```

but my personal favourite is [CLoudinary](https://cloudinary.com/)